Why is 'docker login' timing out?
I have a Debian Linux computer from within which I am attempting to run docker login ... in order to pull a custom docker image. This succeeds when the computer is connected to a router with a LAN cable, however when attempting this while using cellular internet it fails, with the following message:
Error response from daemon: Get "<registry url>": net/https: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
It's not clear to me why this timeout is occuring.

There have been multiple posts concerning this error message and I have tried the solutions suggested, namely configuring my DNS in /etc/resolv.conf.
Prior to editing it I had nameserver 127.0.0.1 in there. I have tried using both Google's DNS server (8.8.8.8) and that of Cloudflare's. Currently the contents of /etc/resolv.conf are:
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options edns0 trust-ad

I have noticed that the 127.0.0.1 nameserver is being automatically added back in even after I remove it using resolvconf. Perhaps this is a clue...
I have also tried explicitly setting the DNS for my cellular connection using:
nmcli con mod CellularCon ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"

But this did not help.
When I run ping google.com I get steady responses with an avg time of 110ms.
